# Java Bigdecimal Range Issue

Tags: java, bigdecimal

For below java Code it dispaly `0E-10` as output

```
 BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("00.0000000000");
 System.out.println(bd); // output is 0E-10
```

`0E-10` is due to range value of Bigdecimal. but is there any way i can display as like input  `00.0000000000` without much coding.?

Comment: What is "without coding" supposed to mean?

Comment: how is this a range issue ? What you are seeing is the scientific notation .

Comment: Ok,Is there any way we can avoid this notation ?,,thanks

Answer (score 1):

BigDecimal#toPlainString() will give the decimal part . Note it doesnt exactly satisfy your requirements

If you the op formatted , use DecimalFormat

Answer (score 1):

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("00.0000000000");
System.out.println(bd.toPlainString()); // output = 0.0000000000
```

As stated by amal you can simply use BigDecimal.toPlainString():

```
public String toPlainString()
   Returns a string representation of this BigDecimal without an exponent field
```